# Subtraction with aggregation using 2 tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

My Laravel query is not working properly. but MySQL query works fine

Laravel Query :

`$data = DB::table(DB::raw('select (sum(case when type="credit" then amount else -amount end)) - (select sum(amount) from total) from report'))`

Please refer mysql query in sqlfiidle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d0343/9

Comment: What do you mean when you say *is not working properly*, what isn't working?

Comment: laravel query shows error

Comment: And what is the error...

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select (sum(case when type="credit" then amount else -amount end)) - (select sum' at line 1 (SQL: select * from select (sum(case when type="credit" then amount else -amount end)) - (select sum(amount) from total) from report)

Comment: Looking at your query and the fiddle, it looks like you just want to get the overall balance, right? So in other words, you could do it with the sum of the credits minus the sum of the debits?

Comment: Yes right... I need to show overall balance

Comment: the sqlfiddle is fine as far as I can see. and the same code works on MariaDB here http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=a3f1e5b59e36b7ef171f07f920ba11b7 so there is some difference between what you have and what we are seeing via your question

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try rewrite your MySQL query, let's simplify it and make it more eloquent.

Assuming `$data` is the overall balance and your model for the report table is called `Report` then the below should achieve what you are after:

```
$data = Report::where('type', 'credit')->sum('amount') - Report::where('type', 'debit')->sum('amount');
```

This will give you the sum of all your credits, minus the sum of all your debits.